# how to insulate attic bathroom vent to prevent condensation

Tags: vent, attic

i bought a house in june and the bathroom fan start dripping water a few weeks ago (november). I looked at the inspection report and the picture shows that the vent duct through the roof isn't insulated. 
Do I need to replace the metal pipe all together or can i just wrap insulation around it?

Another thing is that the pipe isn't long enough to reach to the outside of the roof, so it is venting inside the attic. i am guessing i will have to get a new duct or pipe?

thanks[image]

Comment: Really the vent should angle down and drip to the outside.  If you can't do that just add venting insulation.

Comment: do you mean http://www.homedepot.com/p/Frost-King-E-O-12-in-x-15-ft-Self-Stick-Foam-Foil-Duct-Insulation-FV516/100028603?N=5yc1vZc5hi by "venting insulation"?